# converting python source code to utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8

**Context:**
I am using Google's App Engine (in Python) to connect to Wikipedia's API.
I then get a json file that I use for display on a webpage. 
It is working OK but I am having issues with accentuated/non-Latin characters.

**Actual issue:**
When I query "Nikola Tesla", his name in Cyrillic comes across as python source code instead of utf-8: 
`\u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430 \u0422\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0430`.

As a result, the python source code doesn't get read properly and his name on the webpage shows as `\u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430 \u0422\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0430` instead of Никола Тесла.

How could I convert this python source code into valid utf-8: `\xD0\x9D\xD0\xB8\xD\xBA\xD0\xBE\xD0\xBB\xD0\xB0`

Other than me painstakingly googling individual characters, that is...

Thank you

Comment: Did you try the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file? Also, as a Brazilian developer, I find that Python 3 handles Unicode better. You can use `u`in front of the string (`u'\u2665'`) and try `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Comment: `u"\u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430".encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: @Tico: Thanks but that didn't work either.

Comment: @furas: That did work but my problem is that my string is in a variable.

Comment: @furas: I did try this:
`my_string = "\u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430"`
`new_string = u'%s' % my_string`
`new_string = new_string.encode('utf-8')`
`print new_string`
but I still got the same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is difference between `u"\u041d"` (with `u` prefix) and `"\u041d"` (without `u` prefix) - first is treated by Python as unicode string with unicode letter `\u041d`, second is treated as non-unicode string so Python doesn't recognize `\u041d` as unicode letter.

if you have text without prefix (and you can't add prefix manually) then you have to convert it to correct unicode string using `decode('unicode-escape')`

```
"\u041d".decode('unicode-escape') 

u"\u041d"
```

If you got correct unicode string then you can convert it to "UTF-8"

```
u"\u041d".encode('utf-8')

'\xd0\x9d'
```

-

I use strings in examples but you can use variables with strings.

```
my_string = "\u041d\u0438\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430" 

new_string = my_string.decode('unicode-escape') 

new_string = new_string.encode('utf-8') 

print new_string

Никола
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for that, I had been agonising over this for days!